# calling gawk from an R script

Tags: unix, shell, r, cmd, gawk

Hi i am using R on windows XP i have cygwin on my shell path
what i want to do is send a command to gawk via R shell command this way:
    shell("gawk "{print $1}"", m[1],"_", h[i]."_79.7.dat""}
i get this error
    Error: unexpected '{' in "shell("gawk "{"
how can i fix this problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

escape your  quotes. Example only (not sure what R shell syntax is)

```
shell("gawk \"{print $1}\"", m[1],"_", h[i]."_79.7.dat"")
```

experiment with escaping the quotes to get the correct result.

The other way is to build your gawk command string first , then pass to `shell()`

Comment: Shouldn't the final `}` be a `)`?

Comment: thank you!! another thing i didn't do is add paste()--> shell(paste(("gawk \"{print $1}\"", m[1],"_", h[i]."_79.7.dat""))